# GraphViz - alignment of subgraph

Tags: graphviz, diagram, diagrammer

I'd like to draw a diagram like this.
[image: desired]

But the only diagram I can draw is:
[image: current]

The code I used :

```
graph [rankdir = LR]

node [shape=box]

x1;x2;x3;y1;y2;y3;y4;y5;y6;y7;y8;

node [shape=oval]

ind60;dem60;dem65

{x1,x2,x3} -> ind60[arrowhead=none arrowtail=normal dir=both]

{y1,y2,y3,y4} -> dem60[arrowhead=none arrowtail=normal dir=both]

dem65 -> {y5,y6,y7,y8}

ind60->dem60  dem60->dem65  ind60->dem65
```

How can I draw the desired plot?

Answer (score 7):

A first step in what you want to achieve, using **`rank=same`**, **invisible edges**, **groups**, and **`constraint=false`**:

```
digraph {

node [shape=box]
{
    rank=same;
    y1;y2;y3;y4;
}

dem60[shape=oval];
{y1;y2;y3;y4} -> dem60 [dir=back];

{
    rank=same;
    x2 [group=left];
    ind60[shape=oval];
    dem65[shape=oval];
    y6 [group=right];

    x2 -> ind60 [dir=back];
    ind60 -> dem65
    dem65 -> y6;
}

// Invisible edges to order vertically node groups
edge[style=invis];
x1[group=left];
x3[group=left];
x1 -> x2 -> x3;
node[group=right];
y5 -> y6 -> y7 -> y8;

node[group=""]
edge[style=solid]
ind60->dem60
dem60->dem65

edge[constraint=false];
ind60 -> x1;
ind60 -> x3;
dem65 -> y5;
dem65 -> y7;
dem65 -> y8;
}
```

- `group` enforces vertical alignement of nodes (of the same group).
- `rank=same` makes nodes stay on the same rank.
- Invisible edges enforce rank order within a vertical group.
- `constraint=false` removes constraint calculation for some edges.
- `dir=back` reverses displayed edge direction.

Comment: What is the significance of "rank" in this context. Struggling to find good documentation on that.

Comment: @Josiah Graphviz (dot) determines the _rank_ of each node, mainly by looking at the edges - a node with no incoming edges has the lowest rank, and a node with an incoming edge has a higher rank than the node at the other end of the edge. The rank then is used for the layout - from low (top) to high (bottom). `rank=same` modifies the automatic ranking algorithm and tells graphviz to use the same rank for both nodes, therefore displaying them on the same vertical position.

Comment: Thank you! That helps a good deal.